# Откуда взялось слово "чувак"?

Tags: жаргон, этимология

Я понимаю, что это сленг, но интересно, откуда это слово взялось в русском языке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обсуждалось на разных форумах и в блогах уже не раз...
Но с этим словом много непоняток.
Во-первых, источники расходятся относительно времени возникновения. 70 или 80 годы - это весьма существенно для подобного слова. Но я субъективно отношу его даже к 60-м годам; хотя в своей памяти не уверен, но, вроде бы, слышал его ещё в школе, причем не в самых старших классах... Не уверен, к сожалению.

А вообще достаточно полный список версий есть в Википедии.
При всем к ней скептическом отношении речь идет именно о списке, поэтому возражения о неавторитетности источника считаю неактуальными.

//-----------

О происхождении слова «чувак» нет единого мнения.

Слово чувиха, засвидетельствованное ещё в начале XX века в воровском жаргоне в значении «проститутка», было в 1931 году рассмотрено А. П. Баранниковым, проанализировавшим его как производное от цыганского слова чаво — «парень», то есть «подруга вора»[2].

Переход слова из воровского арго в молодёжное — процесс, который в 1920-е—1930-е гг. отмечал Е. Д. Поливанов[3]. Во-первых, отражение безударного а как у в позиции перед губным спорадически встречается в русской разговорной речи, ср. чумодан < чемодан, сурьёзный < серьёзный, кумпания < компания, фульга < фольга[4], сувать < совать, жувать < жевать, ночувать < ночевать (в последних случаях подкреплено влиянием основы настоящего времени). Таким образом, в данном окружении исконное а вполне могло отразиться как у. Во-вторых, суффикс -ак, которым оформлено заимствованное слово, характерен для большой группы русской экспрессивной лексики и особенно продуктивен в арго, в том числе, в окказиональном словообразовании, ср. студенческое аргот. проходняк «проходной балл», погодняк «погода», верняк «гарантированный успех», ништяк «хорошо, здорово» (также в других арго), воровское арг. ловак «лошадь», парняк «25 рублей» (записаны в начале века[уточнить]). В этот ряд естественно вписывается и образование «чувак» с парной женской формой «чувиха», ср. воровское арго: маз — «мужчина», мазиха — «женщина»[5].

Среди стиляг (то есть в «прозападно настроенной молодёжной среде» 50-х—60-х гг.) «расшифровка» этого слова была такова: «человек уважающий высокую американскую культуру».[6][неавторитетный источник?].

По другим версиям, слово произошло из иврита (тшува — «покаяние», — означающее человека, порвавшего с воровским миром[7]).

Так же существует версия, что это слово, зародившись у «хиппи» в 60-х годах, произошло от английских: chew (жевать) или chewing (жевательный, жующий). Так как в те времена и в той среде «молодёжи» было модно жевать резинку или табак или наркотическое вещество типа насвай.

Также, слово могло первоначально обозначать кастрированного барана или верблюда[1].
//---

Комментарии

Американская ж**е**вачка - это действительно было круто, однако переход сhewing gum в чувака несколько сомнителен фонетически, но более всего - по причине немотивированного переноса
значения объекта на субъект.

История с кастрированным бараном уже напоминает дурной анекдот. Все знают, но никто не может точно сказать, на каком языке, хотя, признаю, внешне очень напоминает что-то тюркское.

"Еврейский след" плох только тем, что никак не связан со значением, в каком-то смысле даже противоречит ему...

Лично я склоняюсь ко вторичному образованию от "чувиха", изложенная версия происхождения которого меня вполне устраивает.

Comment: В середине  60-х  уже  присутствовало  в  молодёжном  сленге.  Вторичная  форма  от  чувихи  -  вполне  убедительно.  Интересно  в  какой  среде  слово  получило  вторую  жизнь.  У  стиляг,  скорее  всего.

Answer (score 3):

Версий конечно много, но мне больше всего импонирует версия происхождения слова от английского `chew` - жевать. То есть `чувак`, это человек жующий жвачку. В 70-х в период движения хиппи это было круто - жевать настоящую ам. жвачку.

Comment: не нужно особо полагать, что это заимствование, достаточно хотя бы нашего глагола чавкать, который родственен chew. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

Answer (score 1):

"Еврейский след" плох только тем, что никак не связан со значением, в каком-то смысле даже противоречит ему...

Воровская лексика вся родом из иврита или идиша. Чувак, фраер, пацан, мудак, малина, ништяк, халява, хана...
Ничего русского.

Answer (score 0):

В начале 60-х я такого слова не помню, а я учился в школе с 61-го по 71-й, в Москве, которая была законодательницей мод в молодёжной культуре. Кроме того, как и всё моё поколение рос на улице, и улично-молодёжный сленг, естественно, знал. А вот в конце 60-х его стали употреблять всё чаще и чаще. В 71-м я пошёл в армию и "чувак" употреблялся повсеместно. Тюркское происхождение вполне уместно. Кастрированный баран, лишённый сексуальных переживаний, вырастает крупным, массивным, физически сильным, мясистым (сюда же амбал-кастрированный поросёнок, мерин-кастрированный конь). Животное становится физически более сильным и работящим (мерин), более упитанным и при забое приносит больше мяса и сала (амбал, чувак). Поэтому крупный не злобный физически сильный парень: или амбал, или чувак. Другое явление 60-х: массовое переселение с конца 50-х до конца 70-х  деревенского население в города, особенно в крупные города, в том числе и Москву, а поэтому такой специфический деревенский термин запросто мог попасть в Московскую молодёжную среду. Как я помню, слово "амбал" (смысл тот же, что и чувак) в 60-е употреблялось даже чаще, чем чувак, но потом "чувак" победил "амбала".

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется, это слово пришло из тюрского языка. Надо спросить у турка, есть ли у них слово "чувак". "Бардак" - тарелка, у них много слов заканчивается на "ак".

Comment: Надо спросить у ясеня...

Comment: `тарелка заканчивается на "ак"` Интересно!

Answer (score -1):

Слово Ч.У.В.А.К. переводится как "Человек Уважающий Высокую Американскую Культуру". Придумали это в России во времена "Стиляг", когда это было модно.) Начало времен стиляг - 1959 год.

Comment: А источник? Я помню то время, если не самое начало, то расцвет. Начало 60-х. Ничего подобного слышать не приходилось.